# Largest Subtree Which is a Binary Search Tree (BST)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

> Given a binary tree, I want to find out the largest subtree which is a
>   BST in it.

This question is duplicate of [Finding the largest subtree in a BST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336148/finding-the-largest-subtree-in-a-bst), where 1337c0d3r gives a O(n) solution by traversing the tree bottom up. There are two lines code confusing me. Can anyone help me explain it?

```
// Find the largest BST subtree in a binary tree.
// If the subtree is a BST, return total number of nodes.
// If the subtree is not a BST, -1 is returned.
int findLargestBSTSubtree(BinaryTree *p, int &min, int &max,
                   int &maxNodes, BinaryTree *& largestBST) {
  if (!p) return 0;
  bool isBST = true;
  int leftNodes = findLargestBSTSubtree(p->left, min, max, maxNodes, largestBST);
  int currMin = (leftNodes == 0) ? p->data : min;
  if (leftNodes == -1 ||
     (leftNodes != 0 && p->data <= max))
    isBST = false;
  int rightNodes = findLargestBSTSubtree(p->right, min, max, maxNodes, largestBST);
  int currMax = (rightNodes == 0) ? p->data : max;
  if (rightNodes == -1 ||
     (rightNodes != 0 && p->data >= min))
    isBST = false;
  if (isBST) {
    min = currMin;
    max = currMax;
    int totalNodes = leftNodes + rightNodes + 1;
    if (totalNodes > maxNodes) {
      maxNodes = totalNodes;
      largestBST = p;
    }
    return totalNodes;
  } else {
    return -1;   // This subtree is not a BST
  }
}

BinaryTree* findLargestBSTSubtree(BinaryTree *root) {
  BinaryTree *largestBST = NULL;
  int min, max;
  int maxNodes = INT_MIN;   // INT_MIN is defined in <climits>
  findLargestBSTSubtree(root, min, max, maxNodes, largestBST);
  return largestBST;
}
```

I've confused by the following two lines code. According to my common sense, after recursive traversing left tree, the `max` variable should be updated, why putting `int currMin = (leftNodes == 0) ? p->data : min;` right after recursive traversing left tree?
The same question for `int currMax = (rightNodes == 0) ? p->data : max;`

```
...
int currMin = (leftNodes == 0) ? p->data : min;
...
int currMax = (rightNodes == 0) ? p->data : max;
```

Comment: The algoritm you need is very close to alpha-beta searching. (except you need to visit *almost* the whole tree and cannot prune)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, this algorithm is traversing the tree bottom up.  After visiting a node's left subtree, one of the following things is true:

1. Left subtree is not BST => current tree is not BST
2. Left subtree is BST => minimum value in current tree is `min`
3. Left subtree has no nodes => minimum value in current tree is the value of the current node

Similarly, after traversing the right subtree, the maximum value in the current tree is either the value of the current node or the maximum value in the right subtree (`max`)

So the line
    `int currMin = (leftNodes == 0) ? p->data : min;`
tests whether condition 2 or 3 is true, and updates the value of `min` accordingly so that the value is correct for testing the nodes above the current node in the tree.