# How to find size of the largest BST in a Binary Tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

```
import java.util.*;

class Node
{
    int data;
    Node left , right;
    public Node (int item)
    {
        data = item;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

class BinaryTree
{
    public static Node root;
    BinaryTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public int largestBST(Node root)
    {
                MinMax m = largest(root);
            return m.size;
    }

    public MinMax largest(Node root)
    {
        if(root == null)
        {
            return new MinMax();
        }

        MinMax leftMinMax = largest(root.left);
        MinMax rightMinMax = largest(root.right);

        MinMax m = new MinMax();

        if(leftMinMax.isBST == false || rightMinMax.isBST == false || (leftMinMax.max > root.data) || (rightMinMax.min <= root.data))
        {
            m.isBST = false;
            m.size = Math.max(leftMinMax.size , rightMinMax.size);
        }

        m.isBST = true;
        m.size = leftMinMax.size + rightMinMax.size + 1;

        m.min = root.left != null ? leftMinMax.min : root.data;//if left node is null take node as min or min of left

        m.max = root.right != null ? rightMinMax.max : root.data;//if right node is null take node as max or max of right

        return m;
    }

    class MinMax
    {
        int max,min;
        boolean isBST;
        int size;
        MinMax()
        {
            max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            isBST = false;
            size = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
        bt.root = new Node(25);
        bt.root.left = new Node(18);
        bt.root.right = new Node(50);
        bt.root.left.left = new Node(19);
        bt.root.left.right = new Node(20);
        bt.root.right.left = new Node(35);
        bt.root.right.right = new Node(60);
        bt.root.right.left.right = new Node(40);
        bt.root.right.left.left = new Node(20);
        bt.root.right.right.left = new Node(55);
        bt.root.right.right.right = new Node(70);

        int size = bt.largestBST(root);

        System.out.println("The size of largest BST is " + size);
    }
}
```

Here the output should be 7 but instead it is showing the total number of nodes in the tree i.e. 11.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Side note: if possible, learn how to write unit tests. It is much more efficient to use Junit to test stuff; compared to use static mains.

Comment: I think you should clarify the definition of the "largest BST in a binary tree".

Comment: Does this not answer the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336148/finding-the-largest-subtree-in-a-bst

Comment: Are you trying to find the largest subtree? In other words, do you want to see if the left subtree is less/larger than the right subtree and vice versa, then return the size of the largest one?

Comment: Yes , I want to find largest Binary Search Tree i.e left part is smaller than the node and right part is larger than the node.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to find the maximum depth of the tree, then rewriting `largestBST(Node root)` like this will do:

```
public int largestBST(Node root)
{
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1 + Math.max(largestBST(root.left), largestBST(root.right));
}
```

What is happening here is that we return `1 + max(left subtree depth, right subtree depth)`. If the node doesn't exist, we return 0 to stop the recursion. This will return `4`.

If by largest, you mean the subtree with the most nodes starting from the given root, regardless of the depth, then we can modify this solution to get the following:

```
public int largestBST(Node root)
{
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    return Math.max(countNodes(root.left), countNodes(root.right));
}

public int countNodes(Node root)
{
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1 + countNodes(root.left) + countNodes(root.right);
}
```

As you can see, the recursion now happens in the `countNodes()` method, and `largestBST()` simply returns the max from left and right branches. The recursion follows the same principle as before. 0 is returned if a node doesn't exist, and we add 1 for each node that does exist. The result will be `7` now.